# What is the size of the menu item?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

What should the size of the menu icon be for items shown in ActionBar? Where can I find native icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android Asset Studio.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html